Automatic Python Environment activation in VSCode March 2024 Update now shows two sets of parenthesis
After the VSCode March 2024 Update I noticed that when I open a new Terminal with automatic Python environment activation it is showing the prompt with two sets of parenthesis:
((.venv) ) myuser@ubuntu23:~/src/myapp$
Where before it was:
(.venv) myuser@ubuntu23:~/src/myapp$
The above is also what I get when I activate the environment manually.
source .venv/bin/activate
I'm running the Terminal in VSCode through a remote SSH connection.
There's been no changes to the host box and my application seems to run without issues, but it's just odd.
I've tried removing the .vscode-server and .vscode directories on the remote host and letting VSCode recreate them.

I suggest you raise an issue ticket. if/once you do, please add a link to it here so I can follow it.

Issue opened:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/209728
